# CPU unsupported by OS - what could possibly go wrong?

Tags: cpu, operating-systems

Background: Microsoft has announced, that the next CPU generations (Intel: Kaby Lake, AMD: Zen) will only be supported by Windows 10. However, due to several reasons, Win10 is not an option for me. But what would happen if I tried to run Win8.1 on a Kaby Lake or Zen CPU?

Of course until the full specs of these CPUs become public the exact answer to that specific question can only be speculative.

Thus the more general question: **What problems are to be expected when running a OS on a CPU it does not (fully) support?** It can be assumed that it supports the general CPU family but not the exact generation. In addition, I'd like to know about problems indirectly caused by a CPU upgrade, e.g. by a newer motherboard required by the CPU.

I'm both interested in the type of problems as well as their severity.

I see two approaches for answers: the theoretical approach and past experience. What does an OS need to support on a CPU and what would happen if it doesn't? Would this lead to disabled features or to crashes? And what happens if you install an old OS on a modern CPU it does not support?

Comment: This question can't be answered because these CPUs don't exist yet.  I would guess it's like trying to use Intel CPU with older OSX before they supported Intel; it'll just not work, but it is entirely a guess.

Comment: I see, you've read the part where I state that I know that and thus ask about problems in the general case.

Comment: The general case is it doesn't work.

Comment: That's why I wrote it can be assumed that other CPUs from the family are supported. I've written that specifically to rule out answers like "you cannot run (x86 OS) on (non-x86 CPU), because the CPU does not understand the instructions"

Comment: You asked "What problems can be encountered?"  The problem is it doesn't work.  Are you asking why?  Because it will cost money to make it work, and they don't want to spend that money.  If you have enough money, you can make anything work with anything.  You can buy Microsoft, then hire a pile of engineers to make Windows 8.1 to work on the new CPU.

Comment: I assume i7-7700 (name guessed) and i7-6700 will not be THAT different. It's not yet known what their exact differences are, but I guess it could work with some new features missing or kind of work but crash in certain situations. Of course I could be wrong and the answer is, that CPUs can reasonably be expected to change so dramatically beween generations that an older OS cannot even properly boot. But that would be a proper answer to my question.

Comment: Not supported does not mean won't work. It means 'we don't know / nor will spend money testing if it will work. Any problems you encounter are on you.' It might work perfectly but they refuse to guarantee this

Comment: "But what would happen if I tried to run Win8.1 on a Kaby Lake or Zen CPU?" - It would work but any new CPU features would not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword here is device drivers.

Not for the CPU itself but for the devices it contains, namely mass storage controllers, USB controllers, graphics adapters etc.

These devices need drivers in order to work properly.

If neither the CPU manufacturer nor Microsoft provide device drivers for a new CPU platform, then there will be limitations in either usability (e.g. limited graphics capabilities if the graphics driver is missing) or it is not even possible to install the OS at all (e.g. if there is no mass storage driver or USB driver).

Case in point, if you want to use Windows 7 with the Intel Skylake CPU family, you have to slipstream the XHCI (USB3.0) driver into the installation medium, otherwise the installation will fail(*) because Windows 7 supports up to EHCI (USB2.0) only.

(*) Assuming you are installing from a USB device and/or use USB input devices.